# How to restore a text file?

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I want to restore the following data from the text file. The problem is only one string/line I can restore, I can't restore the rest of the data.

Here's the code :

```
public static String restore(String filename) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    FileInputStream fn = new FileInputStream(filename);
    ObjectInputStream ob = new ObjectInputStream(fn);
    String sample = (String) ob.readObject();

     return sample;
}
```

Comment: Is that really a text file? Using `ObjectInputStream` suggests that it's actually a binary file with serialized Java object(s) which is created by `ObjectOutputStream`. What exactly is the problem you're having? Does a `ClassCastException` occur or something? How is that file created? Etc.

Comment: Your question is not very clear to me.  If it is a 'text' file, why is the code reading objects?  If it is reading a `Game` object, it should not be reading any 'string/line'.  What is 'the rest of the data'?  One thing that might help answer those questions, and a dozen more, is an SSCCE.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Comment: I already edit the code, you can see it above. It was a mistake earlier.

Comment: @BalusC My problem is I can't restore all the data inside the text file. It only restore the first data I save, but the remaining data can't.

Comment: @Mikel By 'restore' do you mean 'copy'? Or rather do you mean that you inadvertedly copied over the text file that you needed, and now you are trying to restore a file that has been over written?

Comment: If one of the answers are correct you might want to accept one of them.

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to understand the meaning of this question, but if you just want to read lines from a .txt file and into an array, then these two methods might help.

You just need to call `String[] textArray = readFromFile("yourfilename.txt");`
This gives you an array with each line in the file as an element.

```
Scanner fScan(String filename) {

        Scanner sc = null;
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(new File(fname));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found:" + fname + "  " + e);
        }
        return sc;
}

String[] readFromFile (String fname) {
        Scanner sc = fScan(fname);
            int length = 0;
            String lineCounter;
        while (sc.hasNext()){
            lineCounter = sc.nextLine();
            length++;
        }

        String[] array = new String[length];

        sc = fScan(fname);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        array[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }

        sc.close();
        return array;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code does only read the first Element within your binary file.

```
public static void restore(String filename) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    FileInputStream fn = new FileInputStream(filename);
    ObjectInputStream ob = new ObjectInputStream(fn);
    String string1 = (String) ob.readObject();
    String string2 = (String) ob.readObject();

}
```

Are you sure you did not overwrite your file while serializing it?

But as far as I understand your Question you don't want to serialize/deserialize a String-Object, rather than reading/writing a textfile.

If you just want to read/write a file, you are on the wrong way with the ObjectInputStream.

ake a look at:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html